# How to optimize routes with OrTools and assemble matrixDistance?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I'm trying to create an array of distances for 27 addresses, but the returned set is empty. I did not understand. When I only put 24 address, the system assembles the distance matrix.

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import json
import urllib.request


def create_data():
  """Creates the data."""
  data = {}
  data['API_key'] = 'API KEY'
  data['addresses'] = ['R+Carlos+Camara+1454+Benfica+Fortaleza+CE', # depot
                'AV+DEP+PAULINO+ROCHA+105+JABUTI+ITAITINGA+CE',
                'R+CABO+VERDE+660+CJ+PALMEIRAS+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'AV+Monsenhor+AMARILIO+RODRIGUES+604+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+PEDESTRE+IX+349+CANINDEZINHO+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'RUA+MARECHAL+NAPION+733+BARRA+DO+CEARA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+IRACEMA+880+CJ+PALMEIRAS+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+JOSIAS+PAULA+DE+SOUZA+100+VICENTE+PINZON+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+CJ+JOAO+PAULO+II+108+BARROSO+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'AV+XXII+474+SENADOR+CARLOS+JEREISSATI+PACATUBA+CE',
                'R+NUNES+FEIJO+1454+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'AV+A+CJ+JEREISSATI+III+600+SENADOR+CARLOS+JEREISSATI+PACATUBA+CE',
                'AV+CENTRAL+5452+ICARAI+CAUCAIA+CE',
                'R+CJ+JD+CASTELAO+4651+PASSARE+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+FRIESIO+BARROSO+387+MONDUBIM+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'AV+C+CJ+SIT+SAO+JOAO+87+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+BOM+JESUS+200+BOM+JARDIM+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+TENENTE+ROMA+206+ALTO+DA+BALANCA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+SHIRLEY+280+PAUPINA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+TEODORO+DE+CASTRO+2509+GRAJA+LISBOA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'TV+SAO+FRANCISCO+332+MESSEJANA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'RUA+PERDIGAO+DE+OLIVEIRA+361+PARANGABA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'R+ALM+SOARES+DUTRA+33+CUMBUCO+CAUCAIA+CE',
                'R+CORDEIRO+DE+MIRANDA+1311+CJ+METROPOLITANO+CAUCAIA+CE',
                'R+JOAQUIM+MACHADO+287+PAUPINA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                'AV+ENG+LEAL+LIMA+VERDE+306+SAPIRANGA+FORTALEZA+CE', #Conjunto Vazio
                'R+VERDE+180+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE', #Conjunto vazio
                  ]
  return data

 def create_distance_matrix(data):
   addresses = data["addresses"]
   API_key = data["API_key"]
 # Distance Matrix API only accepts 100 elements per request, so get rows in multiple 
 requests.
 max_elements = 100
 num_addresses = len(addresses) # 16 in this example.
 # Maximum number of rows that can be computed per request (6 in this example).
 max_rows = max_elements // num_addresses
 # num_addresses = q * max_rows + r (q = 2 and r = 4 in this example).
 q, r = divmod(num_addresses, max_rows)
 dest_addresses = addresses
 distance_matrix = []
 # Send q requests, returning max_rows rows per request.
 for i in range(q):
   origin_addresses = addresses[i * max_rows: (i + 1) * max_rows]
   response = send_request(origin_addresses, dest_addresses, API_key)
  distance_matrix += build_distance_matrix(response)

# Get the remaining remaining r rows, if necessary.
if r > 0:
  origin_addresses = addresses[q * max_rows: q * max_rows + r]
  response = send_request(origin_addresses, dest_addresses, API_key)
  distance_matrix += build_distance_matrix(response)
return distance_matrix

def send_request(origin_addresses, dest_addresses, API_key):
 """ Build and send request for the given origin and destination addresses."""
def build_address_str(addresses):
# Build a pipe-separated string of addresses
 address_str = ''
 for i in range(len(addresses) - 1):
   address_str += addresses[i] + '|'
   address_str += addresses[-1]
 return address_str

request = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial'
origin_address_str = build_address_str(origin_addresses)
dest_address_str = build_address_str(dest_addresses)
request = request + '&origins=' + origin_address_str + '&destinations=' + \
                   dest_address_str + '&key=' + API_key
jsonResult = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
response = json.loads(jsonResult)
return response

def build_distance_matrix(response):
 distance_matrix = []
 for row in response['rows']:
   row_list = [row['elements'][j]['distance']['value'] for j in range(len(row['elements']))]
   distance_matrix.append(row_list)
return distance_matrix

########
# Main #
########
def main():
"""Entry point of the program"""
# Create the data.
data = create_data()
addresses = data['addresses']
API_key = data['API_key']
distance_matrix = create_distance_matrix(data)
print(distance_matrix)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

With the algorithm below I can optimize the route with the smallest diastence, but I need the sum of the weights to be optimized too, no route can have more than 100, the interesting thing is to stay between 60 and 90. It means that it will be using between 60 % to 90% of the time hired supplying supermarkets, more than 100 means that the service will not be good. But I don't know how to implement this restriction. In this example, vehicle 1 had more than 100, I could throw a store to vehicle 3, which was too low.

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
import pandas as pd


def create_data_model():
  """Stores the data for the problem."""
 data = {}
 data['distance_matrix'] = [[0, 22972, 15918, 14739, 12260, 7874, 16321, 12618, 12136, 20286, 
 14582, 20989, 19583, 12544, 9415, 14593, 8701, 5595, 18205, 10380, 11606, 5471, 28244, 15180, 
 19088], [29448, 0, 18885, 19844, 28925, 36734, 19138, 32722, 20508, 27405, 19013, 27135, 
 48981, 22834, 25845, 16567, 33286, 25147, 13481, 35607, 19994, 32821, 57642, 38376, 14362], 
 [17133, 10750, 0, 2432, 14259, 26384, 1212, 18107, 3544, 16138, 2754, 16841, 34315, 5275, 
 8433, 2767, 18620, 12832, 5699, 20941, 7679, 12922, 42976, 23710, 6582], [16900, 14836, 2916, 
 0, 17169, 24186, 1749, 17227, 2664, 19047, 4152, 19750, 37225, 4395, 8067, 4165, 13139, 
 10225, 8608, 16334, 7446, 12042, 45886, 26620, 9491], [12150, 22554, 16449, 12233, 0, 16331, 
 16702, 24381, 11976, 12050, 17359, 12753, 25224, 11029, 7254, 17372, 4735, 17379, 17503, 
 8396, 16769, 7900, 33884, 14618, 18387], [7851, 31385, 24331, 23152, 15926, 0, 24734, 13912, 
 20549, 25582, 22996, 26285, 12218, 20957, 17180, 23006, 12639, 16703, 26618, 12502, 20020, 
 10883, 20879, 14277, 27501], [17332, 11944, 1217, 2742, 15454, 22085, 0, 17972, 3409, 17332, 
 2953, 18035, 
 35510, 5140, 7273, 2965, 12344, 13031, 6893, 15539, 7877, 13876, 44170, 24904, 7776], [11522, 
 26596, 19542, 16377, 24422, 13517, 18156, 0, 15374, 30601, 18206, 31304, 24449, 15783, 17965, 
 18217, 21085, 8510, 21829, 22975, 15228, 17840, 33110, 24893, 22712], [12495, 13389, 3614, 
 1654, 17867, 19781, 3433, 15191, 0, 19745, 5000, 20448, 30635, 2359, 7887, 5011, 12958, 8189, 
 8622, 16153, 6915, 10007, 39295, 27318, 9505], [20521, 24318, 18212, 19171, 13669, 25953, 
 18465, 31235, 18829, 0, 19122, 500, 33725, 17883, 14108, 19135, 16212, 24232, 19267, 19407, 
 25783, 17744, 42385, 23119, 20150], [16702, 10424, 2545, 3654, 16657, 23987, 2948, 19976, 
 4052, 18535, 0, 19239, 36713, 6378, 9654, 971, 14726, 12401, 5657, 17921, 7247, 14025, 45374, 
 26108, 6540], [20143, 23940, 17834, 18793, 13291, 25575, 18087, 30857, 18452, 500, 18744, 0, 
 33347, 17505, 13730, 18757, 15834, 23854, 18889, 19029, 25405, 17366, 42007, 22741, 19772], 
 [24121, 42972, 36866, 37825, 27254, 12622, 37120, 25838, 32475, 33763, 37776, 34466, 0, 
32594, 28819, 37789, 24278, 28629, 37921, 19467, 31946, 22522, 8661, 11823, 38804], [13864, 
14342, 
4478, 2518, 10725, 19678, 4298, 16560, 1516, 17105, 5953, 17808, 31393, 0, 4866, 5963, 9937, 
9558, 9575, 13132, 6952, 11469, 40054, 23900, 10458], [9744, 18478, 8018, 6553, 7048, 16000, 
6851, 17780, 6295, 13427, 10089, 14130, 27716, 5349, 0, 10099, 6260, 10777, 13711, 9454, 
11088, 7792, 36377, 21641, 14594], [16204, 9926, 2568, 3676, 16679, 23490, 2970, 19478, 4787, 
18557, 971, 19261, 36735, 6518, 9677, 0, 14748, 11903, 5159, 17943, 6750, 19577, 45396, 26130, 
6042], [8518, 26325, 13912, 11952, 5182, 12699, 12157, 21028, 11695, 15374, 15488, 16077, 
25786, 10748, 6973, 15499, 0, 14025, 21274, 3922, 17490, 4269, 34446, 15180, 22157], [4705, 
20812, 13759, 9495, 17540, 11990, 11275, 8803, 8493, 23720, 12423, 24423, 23986, 8901, 11084, 
12434, 14203, 0, 16045, 16094, 9447, 10959, 32646, 19889, 16928], [16517, 7670, 6754, 8533, 
16794, 23802, 7007, 19791, 7577, 18672, 6082, 19375, 36850, 9903, 13714, 4436, 21155, 12216, 
0, 23476, 7062, 19890, 45511, 26245, 1429], [10174, 26621, 16655, 14695, 8462, 12121, 14900, 
22764, 14438, 18117, 18231, 18821, 20668, 13491, 9716, 18242, 3919, 15762, 25091, 0, 19227, 
5239, 29329, 6994, 25974], [11406, 15283, 8229, 5816, 25666, 18692, 8632, 14680, 4860, 27545, 
6894, 28248, 30687, 6866, 11195, 6904, 16266, 7105, 10513, 19914, 0, 14779, 39348, 35117, 
5617], [5409, 25829, 12996, 11036, 7348, 10232, 13028, 17999, 10033, 16523, 17440, 17226, 
21949, 10442, 7538, 17450, 3654, 10996, 21062, 5333, 14461, 0, 30610, 13561, 21945], [32109, 
50960, 44854, 45813, 35241, 20609, 45107, 33826, 40463, 41750, 45764, 42454, 10043, 40582, 
36807, 45777, 32266, 36617, 45909, 27455, 39933, 30510, 0, 19810, 46792], [15615, 31200, 
25094, 26053, 15482, 13846, 25347, 23418, 27165, 21990, 26004, 22694, 12069, 24933, 21158, 
26017, 9839, 22142, 26149, 6158, 32665, 11230, 20730, 0, 27032], [15780, 11894, 8827, 7797, 
19583, 23066, 9576, 19054, 6841, 21461, 5345, 22164, 35061, 9166, 17318, 4847, 23944, 11479, 
1605, 24288, 6326, 19153, 43722, 29034, 0]]
 data['addresses'] = ['R+Carlos+Camara+1454+Benfica+Fortaleza+CE', # depot
                 'AV+DEP+PAULINO+ROCHA+105+JABUTI+ITAITINGA+CE',
                 'R+CABO+VERDE+660+CJ+PALMEIRAS+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'AV+Monsenhor+AMARILIO+RODRIGUES+604+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+PEDESTRE+IX+349+CANINDEZINHO+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'RUA+MARECHAL+NAPION+733+BARRA+DO+CEARA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+IRACEMA+880+CJ+PALMEIRAS+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+JOSIAS+PAULA+DE+SOUZA+100+VICENTE+PINZON+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+CJ+JOAO+PAULO+II+108+BARROSO+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'AV+XXII+474+SENADOR+CARLOS+JEREISSATI+PACATUBA+CE',
                 'R+NUNES+FEIJO+1454+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'AV+A+CJ+JEREISSATI+III+600+SENADOR+CARLOS+JEREISSATI+PACATUBA+CE',
                 'AV+CENTRAL+5452+ICARAI+CAUCAIA+CE',
                 'R+CJ+JD+CASTELAO+4651+PASSARE+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+FRIESIO+BARROSO+387+MONDUBIM+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'AV+C+CJ+SIT+SAO+JOAO+87+JANGURUSSU+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+BOM+JESUS+200+BOM+JARDIM+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+TENENTE+ROMA+206+ALTO+DA+BALANCA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+SHIRLEY+280+PAUPINA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+TEODORO+DE+CASTRO+2509+GRAJA+LISBOA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'TV+SAO+FRANCISCO+332+MESSEJANA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'RUA+PERDIGAO+DE+OLIVEIRA+361+PARANGABA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                 'R+ALM+SOARES+DUTRA+33+CUMBUCO+CAUCAIA+CE',
                 'R+CORDEIRO+DE+MIRANDA+1311+CJ+METROPOLITANO+CAUCAIA+CE',
                 'R+JOAQUIM+MACHADO+287+PAUPINA+FORTALEZA+CE',
                     ]
  data['weights'] = [0,12,15,15,13,7,13,23,10,11,13,9,7,15,8,9,6,11,5,9,5,8,12,13,12]

data['num_vehicles'] = 4
data['depot'] = 0

return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
 """Prints solution on console."""
 print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
 max_route_distance = 0
 matrix_route = []
 matrix_car = []
 for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
    route_distance = 0
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        previous_index = index
        index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
            previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        matrix_route.append(manager.IndexToNode(index)) #Criando a matrix de indices
        matrix_car.append(f"Veículo {vehicle_id}") #Craindo a matriz com o nome das rotas
    plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
    plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
    print(plan_output)
    max_route_distance = max(route_distance, max_route_distance)

#DataFrame with Routes
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(matrix_route,matrix_car), columns = ['Routes', 'Car'])
zero_value = df[df['Routes']<=0]
df = df.drop(zero_value.index)
print(df)

#DataFrame with adresses
df_info = pd.DataFrame(zip(data['addresses'], data['weights']), columns= 
["addresses","weights"])
#df_remove_depot = df_info.loc[df_info['addresses']=='3610+Hacks+Cross+Rd+Memphis+TN']
df_remove_depot = 
df_info.loc[df_info['addresses']=='R+Carlos+Camara+1454+Benfica+Fortaleza+CE']
df_info = df_info.drop(df_remove_depot.index)
print(df_info)

## Merge
tabela = pd.merge(df_info, df, left_index=True, right_on="Routes",how="left")
## Save excel
print(tabela)
tabela.to_excel('C:/Users/mateuscarvalho/Documents/Mateus Carvalho - 2021/Otimização de rotas.xlsx', index = False)

#Menor Distância
print('Maximum of the route distances: {}m'.format(max_route_distance))



def main():
"""Entry point of the program."""
# Instantiate the data problem.
data = create_data_model()

# Create the routing index manager.
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                       data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

# Create Routing Model.
routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


# Create and register a transit callback.
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

# Define cost of each arc.
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

# Add Distance constraint.
dimension_name = 'Distance'
routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    0,  # no slack
    70000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    dimension_name)
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

# Setting first solution heuristic.
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)

# Solve the problem.
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

# Print solution on console.
if solution:
   print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)
else:
    print('No solution found !')


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Answer (score 1):

create a load/weight dimension, add a cumulVarSoftUpperBound of 90 on each node to incentive solver to not overweight ?

first verify

```py
assert len(data['distance_matrix']) == data['weights']
```

Then we can create an extra weight dimension to limit load to 100.

```py
# Add Capacity constraint.
def load_callback(from_index):
  """Returns the demand of the node."""
  # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
  from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
  return data['weights'][from_node]

  load_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(load_callback)
  routing.AddDimension(
      load_callback_index,
      0,  # null capacity slack
      100,  # vehicle maximum capacity
      True,  # start cumul to zero
      'Load')
```

ref: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp

Comment: in this case it is a restriction.  because, for example, I can't send a sales promoter to two stores that sell wholesale, he can't supply.  I have to balance shipping to a small store and a wholesale store.  So I optimize the distance and as a result he will have more time in store to supply them with my products. I'm working for a food Industry

Comment: don't get it, sorry, you can have any number of dimension you want... so while optimizing for total distance traveled you can still add **another** dimension to constrain the maximum weight a vehicle can transport...

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for is, to understand how I can add this restriction. I've looked it up in some articles, but they don't cover it. Adding Constraints in OrTools

Comment: to add advanced constraint you can access to the underline CP solver using `routing.solver()`